# Is there any way to completely change salesforce live agent button to my own design?

Tags: chat

So I would like to change the live agent button, not just font, color, but also to put my change button look completely: upload my own image and so on? What I found: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/embedded_services_web_bootstrap_chat.htm Bootstrap Embedded Chat, but I think this is not the same thing as Live Agent button, as the attributes passed, will be missing some of the information. So is there any way to make my own Live Agent button design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from [Chat Button Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.live_agent_button_settings.htm&type=5). Chat button settings control the behavior of the chat buttons that customers use to interact with agents. You can set your own custom images with Online Image and Offline Image properties.